Can generating the Integers from the Natural Numbers prove equivalent cardinalities?
The Problem
Hi, in MIT's OCW course (18.100A) on Real Analysis by Dr. Casey Rodriguez, one of the problems is whether the set of Natural Numbers ($\mathbb{N}$) has the same cardinality as the set of Integers ($\mathbb{Z}$).
It appears obvious to me that both $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are infinite in size. Even though it's "hand-wavy", I think this means that their cardinalities are equivalent since $\infty$ = $\infty$.
To add some rigour, the professor said that George Cantor's solution to this idea was that two sets A and B have the same cardinality if each element in A can be "paired" with an element in B.
My hacky attempt
I think I found a solution that pairs each element from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ by generating $\mathbb{Z}$ from $\mathbb{N}$.
Here it is:
$\mathbb{Z}$ = $(-1)^{x-1}*\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\rfloor$ for x $x \in \mathbb{N}$
The point of this generation is to say that each member of the natural numbers can be mapped to a member of the integers, thus saying their cardinalities are equivalent. Is this a correct way to generate the integers from the natural numbers?

Assuming the natural numbers don’t include $0$, yes, that’s a bijection between the natural numbers and the integers.

@spaceisdarkgreen thanks so much!

Beware of writing things like $\infty=\infty$ though... next there is a question of whether the set of natural numbers has the same cardinality of the set of real numbers.

$\infty$ is not a cardinality. It is definitely true both sets are infinite, but that does not mean there is a bijection between the two sets. You will eventually learn about the fact that two infinite sets can have different cardinalities

This is great guys! I highly expect this course to get to the real numbers (and comparing them to the naturals) and I'm happy to have fellow scholars point out what the future holds. Thanks again!

Cardinals are equal when there is a bijection between the sets, the most common way to see this bijection is to generate the sequence
$$ 0,1,-1,2,-2,... $$
since sequences are defined as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to the given set, in this case, a function
$$\phi:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$$
is this function injective and surjective? You can clearly see that this is the case.

Yes! I can see that is the case! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.
